# Kivy anchor two widget at each side

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to do a video on top of a graph, with two buttons controlling the graph. I'd like one button to be at the left of the window, the other one at the right, both on the same row, and my problem is placing the - and + buttons.
I have the following kv file, the concerned buttons are the two Control class:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Control>

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: 5, 5
            pos: self.pos



<VideoWidget>:
    video_player: video_handler
    graph: graph_handler
    data_plus: ctr_plus_handler
    data_minus: ctr_minus_handler

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        VideoHandler:
            id: video_handler
            state: 'play'
            options: {'allow_stretch': True}
            size_hint: 1, 0.45
            on_touch_down: root.test()
            on_position: root.move()

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            Control:
                id: ctr_minus_handler
                size_hint: 0.1, 1

                pos_hint: {'left': 0.1}


            Control:
                id: ctr_plus_handler
                size_hint: 0.1, 1
                pos_hint: {'right': 0.1}



        GraphWidget:
            id: graph_handler
            size_hint: 1, 0.45
```

But both Control are taking half the width of the row, whatever I change... Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you want the `Conrols` in the same row as the `VideoHandler` or the `GraphWidget` or in a row of their own?

Comment: In a row of their own, one at the far left the other at the far right, with some padding from the window border if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an empty `Widget` to fill the blank space between the `Controls` like this:

```
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Control:
            id: ctr_minus_handler
            size_hint: 0.1, 1
        Widget:
            size_hint: 0.8, 1
        Control:
            id: ctr_plus_handler
            size_hint: 0.1, 1
```

Comment: That works pretty well for putting the ctr_plus_handler at the right of the screen. However using pos hint to add left padding to ctr_minus_handler doesn't work, and ctr_plus handler is not completely at the right of the screen, kinda feel like I'm missing sometinh

Comment: For a `horizontal` `BoxLayout`, only `y`, `top` and `center_y` pos-hints are honored. If you want to add padding use [padding](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html#kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout.padding).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get that following the orientation, pos_hint parameters would change

Comment: That is because `BoxLayout` does not support horizontal `pos_hint` when using `horizontal` orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FloatLayout instead of BoxLayout with correct pos_hint values. Below is the snippet for the button widget part:

```
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: 1, 0.1
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Control:
        id: ctr_minus_handler
        size_hint: 0.1, 1
        pos_hint: {'left': 1}

    Control:
        id: ctr_plus_handler
        size_hint: 0.1, 1
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
```

Hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: I thought so, but using FloatLayout make the other content of the BoxLayout appear at the bottom of the screen, instead of in the middle